# Query for unique id with XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces

I have the following XML name Sample.xml which I am trying to query uniqueID with XDocument:

```
<Request>
<Person xmlns="http://CompanyName.AppName.version1" uniqueID="3221">
    <AccountNo>83838</AccountNo>
    <FirstName>Tom</FirstName>
    <LastName>Jackson</LastName>
</Person>
<Person xmlns="http://CompanyName.AppName.version1" uniqueID="21132">
    <AccountNo>789875</AccountNo>
    <FirstName>Chris</FirstName>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
</Person>
</Request>
```

How do i write code to extract uniqueID of all persons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ to XML to retrieve the unique ID from your XML document.

```
string xml = "<Request><Person xmlns='http://CompanyName.AppName.version1' uniqueID='3221'><AccountNo>83838</AccountNo><FirstName>Tom</FirstName><LastName>Jackson</LastName></Person><Person xmlns='http://CompanyName.AppName.version1' uniqueID='21132'><AccountNo>789875</AccountNo><FirstName>Chris</FirstName><LastName>Smith</LastName></Person></Request>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XNamespace ns = "http://CompanyName.AppName.version1";
var uniqueIDs = doc.Descendants(ns + "Person")
                   .Select(p => p.Attribute("uniqueID").Value)
                   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code With XmlDocument in place

```
string xml = "<Request><Person xmlns='http://CompanyName.AppName.version1' uniqueID='3221'><AccountNo>83838</AccountNo><FirstName>Tom</FirstName><LastName>Jackson</LastName></Person><Person xmlns='http://CompanyName.AppName.version1' uniqueID='21132'><AccountNo>789875</AccountNo><FirstName>Chris</FirstName><LastName>Smith</LastName></Person></Request>";

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Person");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["uniqueID"].Value);
}
```

Comment: What happens if one of the `Person` elements does not have a `uniqueID` attribute?

Comment: your question is valid. it is just sample snippet, i have not covered all the exceptional cases. user can modify code as per requirement.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the Unique ID by:

```
string xml="Your XML String";
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(xml));
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode node = doc.ReadNode(reader);

foreach (XmlNode chldNode in node.ChildNodes)
{
    if (chldNode.HasChildNodes)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode item in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            string uniqueID = chldNode.Attributes["uniqueID"].Value;
            Response.Write(employeeName + "<br />");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.